# Treating one click as multiple events in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website where there are downloads in various categories, as well as downloads that have themes attached. It isn't important what the file extension is. I view them all as part of an overall download category.

What I am trying to figure out is how - using legacy GA (will migrate soon, but for now just need to gt something working in legacy) - to fire several events for one action.

For instance, consider a download link. The category could be "Policy Papers" but a particular download could also have Theme "Migration". So I need to be able to see stats for Policy Papers as a whole, as well as stats for a given Theme. Would I have to write a separate onClick function that just issues several gaq.push commands? If so, do I have to worry about timing issues between when the download window pops up and when the events are fired?

If I saw a similar example for legacy GA I would be all set and could apply to my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here is probably to define two custom variables "Category" and "Theme" and then set the values of these custom variables to "Policy Papers" and "Migration" respectively. This would be cleaner than firing multiple events. When you move to Universal Analytics, you would use custom dimensions (the "new" custom variables).

Comment: I have since also learned about sending the label parameter in such a way as "category: somecat, theme: sometheme" and that you would then be able to use GA's filtering ability to extract what you need to look at. Your approach is probably cleaner. Just curious what you think about this variation.